# maximum product of n numbers whose sum is k

Tags: mathematics, optimization

We are given two numbers, n and k. We have to find n numbers such that
$$
x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = k
$$
$$
x_1 * x_2 * .....* x_n = maximum
$$

1. What are the values of $ x_1, x_2, ...x_n$ if these numbers can be any real number ?
2. What are the values of $x_1, x_2...x_n$ if these numbers have to be non-negative numbers ?

P.S:

Hexomino  was the first to give the correct solution. But his method requires knowledge of Arithmetic mean and geometric mean .. I am looking for other ways also to solve this question such as those using logic/ mathematical induction/ arithmetic/ calculus, etc .

Comment: This is  perimeter vs. enclosed area(volume, hypervolume...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More elementary solution to the second part, as requested by OP; no calculus etc. required:

> Obviously there is no solution if $k<0$, and there is only one possible solution if $k=0$. Let's suppose $k>0$. Now, suppose we have an optimal solution. (There's a technical issue here: it's conceivable that there might not *be* an optimal solution, just better and better configurations that don't tend to an even better limit. I'll say more about this later.) Suppose the numbers aren't all equal: say $x_i<x_j$. Then consider what happens when we replace $x_i,x_j$ with two copies of $\frac{x_i+x_j}2$. The sum is unaltered. The product changes from $x_ix_jP$ to $\frac14(x_i+x_j)^2P$, where $P$ is the product of all the other numbers. This is an increase, because the difference is $\frac14(x_i-x_j)^2P>0$. So any configuration where the numbers aren't all equal fails to be optimal; so any optimal configuration has all numbers equal (to, of course, $k/n$).

About that technical issue:

> Now that we know what the optimal configuration should be, we can prove that it's actually optimal. Suppose we have any $x$ values at all, and that they aren't all equal. Then at least one will be strictly smaller than $k/n$ and at least one will be larger. Let's say $a$ is smaller, $b$ is larger, and whichever of them is closer to $k/n$ is exactly $\delta$ away. Then what happens when we replace $a,b$ with $a+\delta,b-\delta$? The sum is unaltered. The product increases by $\left((b-a)\delta-\delta^2\right)P$, which is positive because $\delta<b-a$ and so $\delta^2<(b-a)\delta$. And when we do this *at least one number becomes exactly $k/n$*, so after finitely many steps all the numbers are exactly $k/n$, we have arrived at our allegedly-optimal configuration, and the product increased at every step.

Note that we don't really need the first argument above -- but it's a little simpler and helps to motivate the second one.

---

Historical note: originally I misread the question and provided here an elementary solution to a completely different question from the one OP originally asked. At present some of the comments below are about that bogus answer.

Comment: This is the standard answer that we teach in mathematical olympiad courses.

Comment: @Whatsup , which standard answer are you talking about  ? can you please elaborate ? thanks

Comment: But where is the proof that, for the maximum product, m = 0 ?

Comment: Aaaah! I misread the question. The answer here is, as it stands, quite wrong. My apologies. Will edit accordingly, and fix if I see a fix.

Comment: OK, fixed now. Unless I've goofed again, the resulting argument is (1) entirely rigorous and (2) entirely elementary, with no need for calculus or topological notions like continuity and compactness.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal I also read the question wrong. In fact, I took a glance at the answer of Gareth and automatically thought that the numbers were assumed to be integers. IMO that's more interesting than the correct question, which is simply the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan , "originally I misread the question and provided here an elementary solution to a completely different question from the one OP originally asked. At present some of the comments below are about that bogus answer."  What did you originally think the question was ?

Comment: @WhatsUp , assuming that you had thought that both n and k were supposed to be positive integers, can you please tell me which standard answer you were talking about when you had said, "This is the standard answer that we teach in Mathematical Olympiad courses. "  ? Were you referring to this statement by Gareth when you said the above line , " There is always an optimal answer with no two factors differing by more than 1, because if we have factors a,b with a>b+1 then replacing them with a−1,b+1 leaves the sum unaltered and yields a product that has increased by a−b−1≥0." ?

Comment: @hexomino I agree: it's pretty much the usual proof of the AM-GM inequality. That's hard to avoid since in some sense what OP is asking for is _also_ pretty much the AM-GM inequality :-).

Comment: @HemantAgarwal I'm going to guess that WhatsUp misread the question the same way as I did. Or maybe saw my answer and assumed that the question must say the thing I was giving an answer to. [EDITED to add:] In fact, looking at earlier comments I see that WhatsUp has in fact said that that was so.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal My (comically stupid) misreading replaced the requirement that the x's be _nonnegative real numbers_ with the requirement that they be _nonnegative integers_.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Fair point, I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Yes, I was talking about the case where all the $x_i$ are supposed to be integers. This is then a typical problem in mathematical olympiads, and the answer of Gareth is somehow "standard".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I don't know who's more comically stupid - you or me? :D

Comment: @WhatsUp , so this question "x1,x2,...xn are positive integers. x1+x2.....xn= k and x1*x2..xn = max . What are the values of x1,x2..xn ?" This exact same question is used by teachers in Maths Olympiad courses ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Yes, I believe it is, although I don't have reference. [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community) might be a better place to discuss this.

Comment: @WhatsUp , didn't know that the special case of this question ( where all Xs have to be positive integers ) is (possibly) so popular among Olympiad teachers .

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan , I have created another question in which all Xs are required to be positive integers. Can you post your original answer ( using the exact same words )  as an answer to that question ? I wanted to ask a couple of questions about your original answer . This is the link to the new question : https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107092/maximum-product-of-n-positive-integers-whose-sum-is-k

Comment: You appear to have deleted that question now.

Comment: ... Oh, no, it was _another_ near-identical question that you deleted. No sure what the story is there, but never mind.

Comment: Anyway, I'm not going to re-post my answer because Jaap's answer is basically the same and posting mine would add nothing.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan , This is with reference to your original answer. I  wanted to ask how you got the intuition that no two xi should be more than 1 apart. It is very obvious now, after  I have seen your answer . But it wasn't something obvious before I read your answer. P.S : I am trying to teach school students how to approach a question like this.

Comment: Not Gareth here, but as for intuition, for me it comes from the fact that the closer a two number together (with the same sum), the higher is the product. So you want them to be equal, or in the case of integers with different parity, exactly 1 apart.

Comment: @justhalf I realised this now and will use it in my future videos. But was just wondering how someone would first realise that bringing 2 numbers ( with the same sum) closer, results in a bigger product . Does it come from solving problems in parabola, calculus, etc or do you only realise this when you encounter problems like the one I have posted here ?

Comment: @Gareth , thank you for your final and your original answers. Your original answer was the kind of explanation I was looking for . I will be posting my own answer to the other question ( the one where all Xs are positive integers ) but my answer will be mostly based on your original answer. Will give you credit . I know that Jaap has already given a very similar answer there already but had it not been for your answer, I won't have understood his answer.

Comment: If we're talking about intuition, then it comes from trying a few examples. Say, seeing that 5*5 > 4*6 > 3*7, etc. Or if you want visualization, to see that if you want the largest area with the same circumference, you want to make it as "balanced" as possible. So in the case of rectangles, you want a square, which means the two operands are the same. If you want the rigorous proof, Gareth has it in this answer.

Answer (score 6):

Answer 1

> If $n \geq 3$, there is no maximum.
>  To see this, notice that we can pick $x_1$ to be $-1$ and $x_2, \ldots x_{n-2}$ to be $1$ and $x_{n-1}$ and $x_n$ to be $N+1-(n-3)+k$ and $-N$, respectively.
> With this choice, the product grows indefinitely with $N$.
>  For $n=2$ and $k \geq 0$, both numbers must be non-negative to gain the maximum product, in which case we can use the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean inequality to get $$ \frac{x_1+x_2}{2} \geq \sqrt{x_1 x_2} $$ which means the maximum product is $\frac{k^2}{4}$, which occurs in the case $x_1=x_2 = \frac{k}{2}$.
>  A similar argument holds for $k < 0$, where, this time, both numbers must be negative (the result is the same).
>  For $n=1$ the maximum product is trivially $k$.

Answer 2

> Using the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean Inequality we have $$\frac{x_1 + x_2 +\ldots + x_n}{n} \geq \left(x_1x_2\ldots x_n\right)^{\frac{1}{n}} $$ so the maximum product is $\left(\frac{k}{n} \right)^n$ with equality iff $x_1=x_2=\ldots=x_n=\frac{k}{n}$

A different approach for Answer 2

> You could also use Lagrange multipliers here.
>  So, you are maximising $x_1 x_2 \ldots x_n$ subject to the constraint $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n - k = 0$.
>  Solving the partial derivatives gives $x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{n-1} = x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{n-2} x_n = \ldots = x_2 x_3 \ldots x_n = \lambda$ (i.e, the product of any $n-1$ of the numbers is constant.
>  You can see that one of the stationary points has $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_n$ and there are also stationary points where two or more of the $x_i$ are zero.
>  It's not too hard to determine that the case of total equality is a local maximum. A little bit more difficult to see is the idea that you need some (at least two) of the numbers to be negative to top this maximum but this is supported by the locations of the other stationary points (which are saddles in this case).

Comment: Is there a way for someone to find the solution without using the arithmetic-geometric mean inequality ?

Comment: @HemantAgarwal I think it would come out with Lagrange multipliers but, in my opinion, the knowledge behind that is a little more advanced.

Comment: I am looking for answers that don't use some theorems and formulas such as AM-GM and Lagrange multipliers . I am trying to find an answer
 to this question using basic mathematical skills ( calculus ,trignometry, permutations etc are fine though ).

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Well, Lagrange multipliers are a fundamental tool in multivariable calculus, which is the type of calculus you are interested in here. I must ask, is there a particular approach you have in mind already that you want solvers to get?

Comment: I am ideally thinking of something either purely based on logic or based on mathematical induction or if it has to involve calculus then something using Maxima minima ( for n=2, it is easy to see using differentiation that the Maxima will happen when X1= X2=k/2)

Comment: @HemantAgarwal Okay. My own opinion would be that this would be quite difficult. The case n=2 is single variable so regular calculus works here. I would be interested to see another solution which does not incorporate multivariable calculus or indirectly prove the AM-GM in some way.

Comment: See the solution given by "cardinal" to the following similar question . He has given an answer which uses just basic Maths skills :  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67192/how-to-prove-the-sum-of-squares-is-minimum

Comment: You just need to show that if you change 2 values keeping a constant sum, (that means with only one free variable), the maximum product is where the 2 values are equal. (PS: see Gareth's solution)

Answer (score 2):

> Here is another answer to the second question: all $x_i$ have to be equal. Now let $x_1^*\dots x_n^*$ be given with $$ x_1^* + \dots + x_n^* = k $$ such that $x_1^*\cdot \dots \cdot x_n^*$ is maximal.

> The maximum of the product is certainly not zero. So we can assume that all numbers are positive.

> Now take two indices $i\ne j$. Let $s:=x_i^*+x_j^*$ which is positive. Now let all other numbers be fixed and optimize just these two numbers $x_i,x_j$: maximize $x_ix_j$ under the conditions $x_i\ge0$, $x_j\ge0$, $x_i+x_j=s$ (in order to not change the total sum).

> We can subsitute $x_j:=s-x_i$ into the function to maximize, so it remains to maximize $x_i(s-x_i)$ under the conditions $0\le x_i\le s$. This is a simple quadratic maximization (the graph is a parabola open to the bottom), the maximum is attained only at the peak of the parabola, which forces $x_i^*=s/2$ and $x_j^*=s/2$. So $x_i^*=x_j^*$, and since we can do this for all indices $i,j$ this forces all $x_i^*$ to be equal.

Comment: very nice ..can you use this method (preferred ) or some other simple method to solve this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67192/how-to-prove-the-sum-of-squares-is-minimum

Comment: Technically, you have to prove (well, mention) that there is an upper bound to the product, otherwise the argument doesn't work. Currently, what you are showing is "if the numbers are not all equal, it is not a maximum". From this you can not directly conclude "if all numbers are equal it is a maximum". You need to know that a maximum exists in the first place.

Comment: @PaulPanzer , Using calculus we can find the Maxima of xi(s−xi) ..And it can be proven that it is not just a local maxima but a maxima overall.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal That a maximum exists for a 1D subspace doesn't tell you much about the global problem. In fact, if your argument were correct it could also be used on Q1 to prove that there is a global maximum which we know there isn't.

Comment: @PaulPanzer , I am not able to completely follow what you are saying . if you can then do please post another answer which uses the same approach as Daw' s did ( using parabola and Maxima) but with the missing arguments.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal It doesn't warrant a separate answer but the easiest way would be to argue that in Q2 you are on a compact domain, so the image under a continuous function is also compact and therefore contains maxima and minima. Probably more technical than you had hoped for, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @PaulPanzer , what I am getting from your argument is is that consider each xi as a separate dimension ( just like we have x, y, z dimensions in the 3d space )  . If n was, say, 3 then just proving that a maxima exist over x1 and x2 won't be sufficient . we would need to also prove that this Maxima is not just a local maxima in the 2d space of x1 and x2 but is the maxima  in the overall 3d space as well. To prove this, we need to first prove that a maxima exists in the overall  3d space. contd below

Comment: Only after we have proven that a maxima exists in the 3d space can we say that the maxima over x1 and x2 will also be the overall maxima.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal I think you have grasped the most important thing, though the details are a bit jumbled: The proof essentially works by exclusion: 1. There is a global maximum 2. if for any i,j x_i != x_j then we can't be at the maximum because of the parabola argument (but note that replacing x_i and x_j by their average will typically not attain the global maximum because we know nothing about all the other x_k) 3. Having ruled out everything else there is only one point left, namely x_1=x_2=x_3 etc. which has to be the global maximum.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (to Q2) that is neither original nor consensus elementary. I'm posting it because it gives some nice intuition:

> Let's focus on the case where all numbers are positive (negatives are ruled out in Q2 and zeros make  things trivial). We want to show $\prod x_i \le \mu^n$ where $\mu = \frac k n$ is the (arithmetic) mean.
>  
>  As everything is positive we can take the $\log$ to get the equivalent: $\sum \log x_i \le n \log \mu$ (*)
>  The log is a concave (bending right) function, therefore the very intuitive Jensen's inequality applies which essentially tells us that the the center of mass of a set of points on the graph of a concave function always lies below the graph.
>  Translating this statement into a formal inequality and substituting the function and points from our scenario we recover (*).